# Laravel complicated relationship

Tags: laravel

My laravel app structed like this:

- People: Model & Controller
- Pets: Model & Controller. Has **many to many** relationship with **People**.
- Abiilities: Model & Controller.
- People_pets: People pets. (pivot table with `people_id` and `pet_id`). Also has 4 columns of `abbility1_id`, `abbility2_id`, `abbility3_id` and `abbility4_id`.

Now.. I built an API method to return the user pets, and it looks like this:

```
public function pets()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Pet::Class, 'user_pets')->withPivot(
        'abbility1_id',
        'abbility2_id',
        'abbility3_id',
        'abbility4_id'
        )->orderBy('position','asc');
    }
```

which makes `$user->pets` returns the user list of pets, with the pivot information of user_pets and the abbility ids.

**The question**
What I want to do is add a json object to this method result named "abbilities" and get the data of the abbilities there such as name and description from the **Abbilities** model/controller.

How I can add the abbilities information to my query out of just the ID's?

The output of the current API CALL:

[image: Current output]

Desired output: array of Abbilities inside every pet object with the detail of the attack_id's inside `$user->pets->pivot->attack1_id`

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the query builder and `orWhere` to grab the data.  I don't think you can access it through relationships with the way you have it set up.

I don't know how you access your pet ability ids, but I'm guessing it's like `$pet->abbility1_id`.

```
$abbilities = Abbilities::where('id', '=', $pet->abbility1_id)
    ->orWhere('id', '=', $pet->abbility2_id)
    ->orWhere('id', '=', $pet->abbility3_id)
    ->orWhere('id', '=', $pet->abbility4_id)
    ->get();
```

Comment: I don't know how to access it too, since I get it only as the result of the method shown above, in my question \:

Comment: Well if it's pulled in through the many to many relationship, you should have access to it from `$pet`.  What have you tried?

Comment: Hey @DuckPuncher, check my question update, I added my API call result and the desired output to make it more clear to understand what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @TheUnreal, I'm not exactly sure how to do this with multiple ids like that.  I haven't used Laravel in a while, and I don't have a way to do any tests at the moment.